# Why the “which is” can be omitted?

Tags: grammar, clauses, attributive-nouns, which-that

I am writing a scientific paper. And I wrote the sentence as follows:

The nominal prepreg tow height is about 0.15~0.20mm, which is much larger than the Resolution Z-axis (0.011mm). Furthermore, the tow gap nominal width is about 0.1mm~1mm, **which is** much larger than the Resolution X-axis (0.056mm).

However, my tutor supervisor advised me to remove the second marked "which is". I do not know why. Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks so much.

Comment: Why didn't you ask him?

Comment: There isn't much of an explanation. The sentence makes perfect sense both ways. The mark of a particularly poor proofreader is somebody that corrects things to the way they would write them exactly.

Comment: *Nominal*, in this instance, implies stated or named. So it wouldn't be *about* some number, it would be *precisely* some number. Nominal values may not be accurate, but they are precise. "About" should not be used with ranges of numbers. If you mean typical, say typical. And it should read "Z-axis resolution" and "X-axis resolution".

Comment: While we don't normally rewrite stuff for people, I'd recast the whole affair as follows:  The prepreg tow height is much larger than the Z-axis resolution—about 0.15–0.20 mm compared to 0.011 mm. Furthermore, the tow gap width much larger than the X-axis resolution—about 0.1–1.0 mm compared to 0.056 mm. Add spaces between numbers and units. Use en-dash, not tilde, for range separator.

Comment: It's simply a good idea to leave witches out of scientific papers.

Comment: Special thanks to all of your comments!

Answer (score 1):

It might be simply that as a repetition of the previous pattern of thoughts, it can be abbreviated. As in "Steven eats the cake; Amy, the potato" instead of "Steven eats the cake; Amy eats the potato".

Comment: I'd prefer an 'and' or a 'while' in lieu of the semicolon.